# Ajax request returning whole page half the time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I got a HTML select-box containing arround 20 different number codes (i.e. "123456790") as select options, with an onChange trigger that is initiating a regular Ajax POST, which is supposed to set the text for a specific HTML element. The code is like this:

HTML

```
<select id="mtn_select" name="mtn_select" onChange="setDetailValues(this.value);">
<option value="0" selected>Please select</option>
<?
    foreach ($servicearray as $serviceno => $element) {
        echo '<option value="'. $serviceno .'">'. $serviceno .'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

JS

```
function setDetailValues(select_value) {
    if (select_value == 0) {
            $('#service_city').text('');
    } else {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'modules/ajax_maintenance.php',
    data: { servicenumber : select_value },
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(return_data)
    {
        if (return_data) {
            var myarr = return_data.split("|");
            $('#service_city').text(myarr[1]);
            } else {
                    $('#service_city').text('no data found');
            }
    },
    error: function(return_data)
    {
            $('#service_city').text('an error occured');
    }
});
```

PHP (ajax_maintenance.php with hard-coded values for now)

```
<?
$service_nr = strtolower($_POST['servicenumber']);
$service_city = "New York";
$service_str = "Someplace 22a";
$return_value = "";

$return_value = $service_nr ."|". $service_city ."|". $service_str;
echo $return_value;
?>
```

Now this is rather simple and it works as intended, but unfortunately still breaks like half the time. When it works the XHR-POST response (checked via Firebug) will be "123456789|New York|Someplace 22a" as expected and the city value will be updated just fine.

But every other POST response will contain the whole HTML website code from `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` til the very last line `</html>`. When this happens the ajax-call does not recognize it as an error nor as missing data, so the HTML code of the whole website will be inside the "return_data" callback variable and printed out on the website, where the city value is supposed to appear.

The website this stuff is integrated into is a bit complicated with quite a lot (unknown to me) php-includes, utilizing GET parameters for the currently selected module (so all links point to index.php with different params) and the session ID of the current user.  At first I thought this could be a problem (due to the authentication/authorization stuff and the SID) so I manually added the GET params to my ajax-POST, but this did not change anything. I assume it has to be something server side and with the session handling, but I am really flabbergasted why this ain't happening all the time and at a loss what to test/change in order to advance.

Comment: Just a suggestion, return the data as json, so you don't have to do all that splitting business. 

Also this sounds like the ajax request might be returning an error page, since ajax_maintenance.php doesn't really have <html> tags or anything. Pastebin the whole html returned please.

Comment: Yes, use JSON, it's very suited for this. As for your issue, next time you get a failure, check the request parameters for your outgoing request in Firebug. I suspect you'll see something unexpected there.

Comment: is it me or is the .php file not correct ? It has not the right opening tag, which can lead to an error (unless short tags is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

The datatype value of your post request looks incorrect. You should modify your php script to return json formatted data, and change the datatype to be json.

Something like this for the php:

```
$return_value = json_encode(array($service_nr, $service_city, $service_str));
echo $return_value;
```